# MySQL insert into different databases tables based on PK value

Tags: mysql, insert, sharding

Lets assume i have two databases, both having a table 'user_feedback', sharding data between the two databases. My goal is to insert all records where Primary key Id%2=0 goes to db1.user_feedback, and Id%2=1 goes to db2.user_feedback.

Is there a condition in the INSERT statement that can allow me to do this? How can i achieve simply achieve this, both if the two databases are located on the same MySQL server, and when they both reside on a different MySQL server?

** UPDATE **
Ok, what i am trying to achieve is to have several tables in the same MySQL server to shard data and limit one table from becoming too big, hence slowing up queries on this table. The table is expected to grow very large (billion records) with heavy writes. That is the reason we have decided to resort to sharding. The table does not currently exist, but we want to create this shard solution in advance before we hit production with this table.

Comment: this won't get a performance gain. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There is no INSERT variant which inserts the records into 2 separate tables. You need 2 queries to perform your action.

Comment: @Akina, maybe you are right. So i may need some a way to first determine if Id%2 is 0 or 1, then use two queries to perform inserts appropriately based on the value provided.

Comment: *maybe you are right* I guarantee. [INSERT syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html). Only single-table variants are documented. *i may need some a way to first determine if Id%2 is 0 or 1, then* No. You should do this directly in the queries.

Comment: *My goal is to insert all records* What is the source of these records that must be inserted?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by doing this directly in the queries. The goal here is to perform writing (separate) data into two shards since one table is not big enough to hold the data. About the inert syntax, i am not refusing that an insert can only write data to one table at a time. The Data source is a web Application, and that is what complicates the task. If it was from another table in some database, then this could have been not as complex.

Comment: One way i can think of to achieve this is to keep a counter in the code/application level of the number of records assuming also that Primary keys are stored as incrementally. For example, if the current counter is 10, then before deciding which shard (table) to send a new record to, we need to perform a condition check of (10+1)%2, and if the result is 0, then INSERT into tb1.user_feedback, otherwise insert into tb2.user_feedback. However, this method would require doing this on the code-level.

Comment: @user172927 - Tables are arbitrarily large; how can "one table not be big enough to hold the data"??

Comment: If a table has billions of records, it would slow down reads. I have updated the original question so please refer to it for more details. But ya, the goal is to avoid performing reads on a super large table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am extremely dubious that you have the problem you describe, but here goes:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ...   (the rest of the columns)
    );

INSERT INTO t
    SELECT * FROM source;

INSERT INTO db1.x  SELECT ... FROM t WHERE id % 2 = 0;
INSERT INTO db2.x  SELECT ... FROM t WHERE id % 2 = 1;
```

If the data is coming from clients that are feeding the data in fast and furious, then I recommend ping-ponging between two temp tables, not between even/odd.  The clients will `INSERT` into one temp table while a separate task is copying the other temp table into one of the two 'real' tables.  Then that task will `TRUNCATE` the table it copied, then `RENAME TABLE` to atomically swap the temp tables.

I discuss that in more detail in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table

Comment: Hi @Rick James. Actually the problem situation is real. Might be a better way to think of solving the problem, but for now this is exactly what i want to achieve. So i will accept your answer for it works. However, wouldn't there be serious lags for the whole process to take place and eventually get data into db1.x and db2.x especially if the newly inserted data has to be read almost right away?

Comment: @giogio - How many rows per second?  If under 100/sec, there is not likely to be any real lag.  If over 1000/sec, it might never catch up.  In between 100 and 1000, there will be a small lag, but the processing will be more efficient, hence it won't get "behinder and behinder".

Comment: If can handle 100-100 queries per second with minimum and non-progressive lag then that should be accepted. It seems i would need an INSERT trigger to run INSERT INTO t SELECT * FROM source as soon as data is added to the source right?

Comment: @giogio - No.  That leads to backlogs that it may not recover from.  The ping-pong technique lets rows be buffered, then efficiently flushed.  Note that handling 100 rows in a single SQL statement takes about as long as 10 statements, each handing only one row.  I would expect the lag to be much less than 1 sec. when running at 100 to 1000 inserts/sec. and no Trigger.

Comment: Then whats running the statement  INSERT INTO t SELECT * FROM source  in your example? Can you please shade more light on the so called ping-pong method? And for the "source" table, should it also be created with "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE source..."?

Comment: @giogio - But first, I need to know where the records come from.  You first mention them in "My goal is to insert all records..."  All what records?  Are they in some other table?  Are they being provided by clients one at a time?  Or what?  (I have a separate process continually running -- swapping tables and processing one while the other is being refilled.)

Comment: The records are coming from an Application as its processing hundreds of user data per second. So this data is not from a table, but rather coming directly from client Application.

Comment: @giogio - Is it doing hundreds of 1-row `INSERTs` per second?  It would be more efficient to gather a 100 rows into a single `INSERT` and toss them into one of the tables all at once.  Then put the next 100 into the other table.  Please explain why you need to alternate.

Comment: I have updated the original question so please refer to it for more details. But ya, the goal is to avoid performing reads on a super large table.

Comment: @giogio - I don't understand how any of these ideas will significantly decrease the number of "reads on a super large table".

Comment: I simply just want to shard my data on a table between multiple databases.

Comment: @giogio - Is there an intellectual exercise?  It can't be a performance issue; nothing will be gained.  It will increase, not decrease the disk footprint.  I am having trouble imagining some other reason to do what you devised.  I ask about the underlying intent in case I can point you in some other direction that may achieve the "real goal".

Comment: Hi @Rick James. The underlying intent is to shard data on a table that is growing super fast, that way the data and load is shared between multiple copies of the same table residing on different shards. Each table shard will be on a different database (but same MySQL server).

Comment: @giogio - Eh?  Sharding makes sense only if each shard is on a different physical server!

Comment: That is fine. Infact, that is the goal. I used the same server just for testing purposes as the idea solution would work also for shards on different machines. But now my question is, how can the client know which database (node) has the data its looking for since each shard will contain only a part of the data?

Comment: @giogio - Picking the shard -- start a new Question.  Or, better, find an existing question that discusses such.  Your simple modulo solution has some serious flaws.  So does dictionary lookup.  I discussed a 'hybrid' approach.

Comment: Hi @Rick James. You are right.  I started a new thread with a different question here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/231901/reading-from-two-shards-using-proxysql

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try the below query.

```
insert into db1.user_feedback as select * from db2.user_feedback where < your 
conditions>;
insert into db2.user_feedback as select * from db1.user_feedback where < your 
conditions>;
```

Comment: This would not work as both tables start off empty, and record placement in each shard will depend on whether the value of Id%2 is 0 or 1 i.e., If Id%2=0, insert into tb1.user_feeback,else if id%2=1, insert into tb2.user_feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Use the stored routine:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `splitinsert`( IN _param1 INT, ... )
BEGIN
  SELECT max(id) INTO @t1 FROM db1.tbl1;
  SELECT max(id) INTO @t2 FROM db2.tbl2;
  IF @t1 < @t2
    THEN 
      INSERT INTO db1.tbl (id, col1, ... )
      VALUES (@t1+2, _param1, ... )
    ELSE 
      INSERT INTO db2.tb2 (id, col1, ... )
      VALUES (@t2+2, _param1, ... )
  END IF;
END
```

And then:

```
CALL splitinsert(1234, ....);
```

Sure you have to initialize both tables by seed records.