# Reading from two shards using ProxySQL

Tags: mysql-5.7, sharding, proxysql

I have a table that has been sharded between two machines, and the same table on each machine holds different data (not replicated).

With ProxySQL, how can I create a mysql_query_rule that allows a client to perform a SELECT on the appropriate shard?

Or if I perform the query as:

> select * from table_name where id=5

Then how would ProxySQL know which shard (machine) has the record with id=5?

Comment: (I made two substantive changes to the wording; please verify that I did not mess up the intent.)

Comment: The intent has not changed. Thanks